# Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Please point out every problem you see with this code. Any fundamental flaws, naming conventions, design decisions, you name it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class SieveHelper {
public:
    SieveHelper() : cur(2) {}

    bool operator()(unsigned int i) {
        return i != cur && i % cur == 0;
    }

    unsigned int cur;
};

void sieve(std::vector<unsigned int>& arr) {
    SieveHelper helper;
    auto it = arr.begin();

    while (it != arr.end()) {
        helper.cur = *it;

        auto last = std::remove_if(it, arr.end(), helper);
        arr.erase(last, arr.end());

        it++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<unsigned int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        arr[i-2] = i;

    sieve(arr);

    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](unsigned int i) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A classical prime sieve is probably not implemented in terms of erasing from a vector. http://ideone.com/8yKTK is an example, optimized for minimizing memory usage. sieve_vec is a table of booleans where indexes correspond to odd values 1, 3, 5, 7, ...

Comment: As to difference in speed compare http://ideone.com/MB3VJ (primes up to 10,000,000 in 0.08 seconds) and http://ideone.com/BKQXd (up to 200,000 in 2.5 seconds).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I sort includes alphabetically, making it easier to keep track of which headers are included in long lists.

I would write:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

In a long, unsorted list of includes it's hard to see if a header is included twice:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <new>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Imagine this problem increasing if you have a couple dozen includes!

- `arr` is very undescriptive, and in this case even misleading. This isn't an array, it's a `std::vector`. `vec` would be slightly better, but try to describe what the data structure contains or does rather than what kind of data structure it is. Even something as simple as `numbers` is better than `vec` (or `arr`), and you can probably improve that even further. Naming is very important to ensure readability.
- Consider using [<cstdint>](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_cstdint.htm) to control the size of numbers. This makes porting a whole lot easier.
- In C++, it's a good habit to prefer prefix increment- and decrement-operators, because they are usually more efficient for non-built-in types. It doesn't really matter for built-in types, but consistency is nice.
- Consider using `using`-declarations, i.e. `using std::vector;` and so on, to make the code more readable.
- I'd usually make `SieveHelper::cur` private and control access to it, but I presume you know that and did it this way on purpose. It's fine for a small program, but remember that programs grow.
- Use `std::vector::at()`, which is bounds-checked, whenever array indexing is not in the speed-critical path. The exception is when you're 110 % sure you can never, ever go out of bounds - but better safe than sorry!
- Consider making `sieve()` take and return an argument, rather than just manipulate an output argument. This is definitely a trade-off, so use your own judgement, but output parameters are generally less readable.

On the plus side, this is mostly good. Extra points for using built-in algorithms, lambda and other juicy C++11 stuff :)

Comment: don't agree with using at() as default. I would prefer operator[] as default using at() only when data comes from user (unvalidated input). If you can't guarantee the values on validated code then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @LokiAstari I agree that you should never actually have an exception thrown from `at()` - but that means even more reason to use it, because its cost is then practically the same as `operator[]`. However, if you *do* get an exception from `at()`, then it's much easier to debug. Also, we should swallow our hubris and write robust code when we can ;)

Answer (score 6):

Where you use `while()` I would prefer to use `for(;;)` (and use pre-increment).
Not a big deal but I like to keep all the loop control in one place

```
auto it = arr.begin();

while (it != arr.end()) {
    // STUFF

    it++;
}

// I prefer (though not much different)

for(auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it)
{
    // STUFF
}
```

Rather than have SieveHelper being declared once and then updated each time through the loop. Just create a new one each iteration. The actual cost of construction will be optimized to zero and it becomes easier to read.

```
    helper.cur = *it;

    auto last = std::remove_if(it, arr.end(), helper);

// I would do this (note it requires slight modifications to SieveHelper (see below)).

    auto last = std::remove_if(it, arr.end(), SieveHelper(*it));
```

Keeping const correct is a good habit to get into. You need to apply this to your SieveHelper. Also for simple helper functions like this I like to make them structs

```
struct SieveHelper
{
    bool operator()(unsigned int i) const  // object not changed by method => const
    //                              ^^^^^
    {
        return i != cur && i % cur == 0;
    }

    // Use a reference (as we don't need to store state in the helper)
    SieveHelper(unsigned int const& c) : cur(c) {}
    private:
    unsigned int const&  cur;
};
```

Since you are using C++11 we can even simplify this to a lambda

```
auto last = std::remove_if(it, arr.end(), 
                           [&it](unsigned int i){ return i != (*it) && i % (*it) == 0;}
                          );
```

As an optimization (probably not a big one) you don't need to call erase after each iteration:

```
void sieve(std::vector<unsigned int>& arr)
{
    SieveHelper helper;
    auto it   = arr.begin();
    auto last = arr.end()

    while (it != arr.end()) {
        helper.cur = *it;

        last = std::remove_if(it, last, helper);

        it++;
    }
    arr.erase(last, arr.end());
}
```

Now if we apply all these (apart from lambda)

```
void sieve(std::vector<unsigned int>& arr)
{
    auto last = arr.end()

    for(auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it)
    {
        last = std::remove_if(it, last, SieveHelper(*it));
    }
    arr.erase(last, arr.end());
}
```

Comment: Good comments, and I also prefer `for` over `while`. While `while` may be more readable, it spills a variable into the surrounding scope, and with `while` it's easier to neglect the incrementing statement.

Comment: Wow, I'm really glad you came in and replied even after I already chose an answer because this is really great! Any chance you could point me to an article about the particular compiler optimization on constructing each iteration?

Comment: Sorry I don;t have an article. You should be able to see it by generating and examining the assembly produced.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you adding `1` to your array?

I can give a simple performance hint. You know that every even number except 2 is composite, so in initialization of `arr` do not add even numbers (and of course you should not check for 2 in your `sieve` function). Something like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> arr(n/2+1);
arr[0] = 2;
for (int i = 3; i <= n; i+=2)
    arr[i/2] = i;
```

or you can go further and do not add multiples of 2 and 3. For walking over numbers which are not multiples of 2 and 3, you should first take a step of size 2 and then take a step of size 4 and again 2 and again 4 and ...

```
std::vector<unsigned int> arr(n/3+1);
arr[0] = 2;
arr[1] = 3;
int t = 2;
for (int i = 5; i <= n; i+=t, t=6-t)
    arr[i/3+1] = i;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the 1. I removed that from the above code.

Answer (score 3):

I like closing *for* and *if* one liners just to prevent accidental addition of code that doesn't get executed or put the entire thing on one line, but that may just be me.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {arr[i-2] = i;}
```

or

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  arr[i-2] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this still gets listed near the top rank under "Sieve of Eratosthenes": the code under review does **not** implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes at all, it is **trial division** pure and simple.

The real Sieve of Eratosthenes avoids division, and that makes it orders of magnitude faster. Even millions of times when numbers get big enough.

The [wikipedia article for SoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) explains it well, and there are [plenty of code examples for it at Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in many languages. A couple more are on [this page](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SieveOfEratosthenesInManyProgrammingLanguages).

The best overview from a programmer's perspective is probably [Achim Flammenkamp's page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/prime_sieve.html).